# Run rake tasks in sequence

Tags: ruby, rake

I have rake tasks which i want to run in proper sequence.

I want to run one rake task which run other rake tasks in proper sequence.

How may i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should consider defining dependencies between your tasks like this

```
  task :primary => [:secondary]

  task :secondary do
    puts "Doing Secondary Task" 
  end
```

But if you really, really need to call the tasks directly you can use `invoke` to call another task

```
  task :primary do
    Rake::Task[:secondary].invoke
  end

  task :secondary do
    puts "Doing Secondary Task" 
  end
```

see also [here](http://docs.rubyrake.org/user_guide/chapter04.html)

Comment: if my all tasks in different files than how may i run those tasks from one task.

Comment: try to require the file where the tasks are defined from the file where you want to call the tasks

Comment: can you give me idea how may i pass parameters with invoke statement.

Comment: by adding them as parameter to invoke - invoke(param1, param2,...)